# Battleships random orientation

Tags: ruby

i have created a way for it to choose horizontal or vertical randomly. I am stuck at how i should make it so my battleships align in the correct orienatation, and how to choose the starting co-ordinates using my x_var and y_var's.

```
require 'colorize'

def board
  ship_type = Hash["5" => "aircraftcarrier", "4" => "cruiser", "3" =>"destroyer1", "2" => "destroyer2", "1" => "submarine"]

  x_var = rand(0-9)

  y_var = rand(0-9)

orientation = ["h","v"]

  var = rand(0-2)

  if orientation[var] === "h"

    puts "horizontal!"

  else

    puts"vertical!"

  end

  puts "enter the x co-ordinate"

  x_input = gets.chomp.to_i

  puts "enter the y co-ordiante"

  y_input = gets.chomp.to_i


  arr = Array.new(10, ".").map{|y| Array.new(10, ".")} #creates the 10x10 grid


  y_axis = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"] #labels the axis

  x_axis = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]


  print "\t"

  print y_axis.join("\t")

  puts


  arr.each_with_index do |y, i|

    print x_axis[i]


    print "\t"

    arr[x_input][y_input]= " ".colorize(:color => :light_blue, :background => :red)

    print y.join("\t")

    puts

  end

end

    puts


  puts



board
```

Comment: don't you want to use to `rand(0..9)` instead of `rand(0-9)`?

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if it were single-spaced. Also you probably want `==` in `if orientation[var] === "h"`, there are some miscellaneous lines after the method's `end`, and if your question has nothing to do with `colorize`, you should remove the `require` and replace the line containing `.colorize` with, say, a comment.